# Merge sort with a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I am trying to make a merge sort algorithm with the stl library but am having some issues. Below is the code I am using

```
template <typename Item, typename SizeType>
void merge_sort(Item array[], SizeType size){
    size_t n1; //Size of the first subarray
    size_t n2; //Size of the second subarray

    if(size > 1){
        //Compute the size of the subarrays
        n1 = size/2;
        n2 = size - n1;

        //create the temp array.
        int* n1Temp = new int[n1];
        int* n2Temp = new int[n2];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            n1Temp[i] = array[i];
        for(i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            n2Temp[i] = array[i + n1];

        //recursive calls
        merge_sort(n1Temp, n1);//sort from array[0] through array[n1 - 1] 
        merge_sort(n2Temp, n2);//sort from array[n1] to the end

        //Merge the two sorted halves.
        vector<int> v(array, array + size);
        merge(n1Temp, n1Temp + n1, n2Temp, n2Temp + n2, v.begin());     
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), array);//copy the vector back to the array

        delete[] n1Temp;
        delete[] n2Temp;
    }
}
```

The code sorts fine but the problem is that it acts like a O(n^2) algorithm instead of O(n \log n), which is due to the creation of the vector in each merge sort call (I think). I tried removing the vector and just using an array in the merge function which can be seen below

```
    //Merge the two sorted halves.
    int* finalArray = new int[n1 + n2];
    merge(n1Temp, n1Temp + n1, n2Temp, n2Temp + n2, begin(finalArray)); 
    array = finalArray;
```

But this gets me nothing but errors. Is there any thing I can do to salvage my merge sort algorithm?

Comment: Why not merge `n1temp` and `n2temp` directly back into `array`?

Comment: `merge(n1Temp, n1Temp + n1, n2Temp, n2Temp + n2, array);`  should work - what errors do you get with this?

Comment: That does work! Both of you guys are right. The errors I was getting was because I was trying to use an iterator with the pointer array.

Comment: But still use std::vector<>, only for the partitions rather than the target merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As both Vaughn and user93353 pointed out, you should be able to merge directly into the target array at each merge-point. But you can still use std::vector<> to make this significantly easier on yourself.

Also, your temp arrays are of direct type 'int', and I'm fairly sure that was intended to be the type of the template parameter `Item`. I'm not sure what the `SizeType` parameter is for, but I left it in case you had special ideas for it. Whatever it is, it better be compatible with `size_t` :

```
template <typename Item, typename SizeType>
void merge_sort(Item array[], SizeType size)
{
    if(size > 1)
    {
        //Compute the size of the subarrays
        size_t n1 = size/2;

        //create the temp array
        std::vector<Item> n1Temp(array, array+n1);
        std::vector<Item> n2Temp(array+n1, array+size);

        //recursive calls
        merge_sort(&n1Temp[0], n1);       //sort array[0] through array[n1-1]
        merge_sort(&n2Temp[0], size-n1);  //sort array[n1] through array[size-1]

        // merge the sorted halves
        std::merge(n1Temp.begin(), n1Temp.end(),
                   n2Temp.begin(), n2Temp.end(), array);
    }
}
```

The above technique splits the sub-sequences top-down via copy, then merges in-place the split-copies into the original array. You can reduce this algorithm by one sublist allocation *time* (but no less space) by doing the splits on the original array, then merging into temp-space and copying after, which i *think* you were trying to do in the first place:

```
template <typename Item>
void merge_sort(Item ar[], size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        // Compute the size of the subarrays
        size_t n1 = n/2;

        // invoke recursion on the submerges
        merge_sort(ar, n1);      //sort array[0] through array[n1-1]
        merge_sort(ar+n1, n-n1); //sort array[n1] through array[size-1]

        // create merge-buffer
        std::vector<Item> mrg;
        std::merge(ar, ar+n1, ar+n1, ar+n, back_inserter(mrg));
        std::copy(mrg.begin(), mrg.end(), ar);
    }
}
```

---

**General Iterator-Based Solution**

For a general solution that allows even more flexibility you can define your merge-sort based on iterators rather than Item pointers. It gets a little more hairy, but the benefits are very std-lib-ish.

```
template <typename Iterator>
void merge_sort(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type difference_type;

    difference_type n = std::distance(first, last)/2;
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    // invoke recursion on the submerges
    merge_sort(first, first + n);
    merge_sort(first + n, last);

    // create merge-buffer
    std::vector<value_type> mrg(std::distance(first, last));
    std::merge(first, first+n, first+n, last, mrg.begin());
    std::copy(mrg.begin(), mrg.end(), first);
}
```

---

Finally, if you find yourself sorting a ton of fixed-length C-arrays you may find the following helpful (it uses the general-iterator solution above):

```
// front-loader for C arrays
template<typename Item, size_t N>
void merge_sort(Item (&ar)[N])
{
    merge_sort(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));
}
```

It make the following code rather convenient:

```
int arr[1024];
... fill arr ...
merge_sort(arr);
```